# android aar file file empty/no .class file after updating build Gradle to 7.3.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

After updating

From
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2' to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
```

and try to Create aar file for my library project, its creates aar file with less size where I could see **no .class files** at all, So forth the app which is importing this library gets method not found error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxX2P.png)

I am using compileSdkVersion 33 &  targetSdkVersion 33 in both app & library project.
Used gradle-7.4-all.zip

Tried decremented to 32 too, but no effect.

With 7.2.2 all good. I could see .class file available.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EvVs.png)

How to resolve this issue, I don't have option to degrade gradle option, I must have to update in order to support apps with latest gradle version